# How to ssh with Amonite supplying the password in advance

Tags: scala, ssh, ammonite

> `Problem: I need to access a command line API on a Remote machine.`

I am playing with Scala Amonite libs, i wonder if there is a way to ssh and supply the password, so that i can do it from within an application and not have to enter the pass in the middle of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use [public key authentication](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication) not passwords. It's a best practice regardless, & solves your problem of ssh from inside a script without having to provide a password.